# Variable "polls" does not exist in

Tags: php, symfony

```
/**
* @Route("/DeletePoll/{pollId}",name="poll_delete")
* @Template()
*/
public function DeletePollAction($pollId) 
{
    $entita = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle:Poll')->find($pollId);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($entita);

    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle:Poll:index.html.twig');
}
```

In my index.html.twig

```
{% if polls %}
    {% for poll in polls %}
<a href="{{ path('poll_delete',{'pollId': poll.id}) }}">Delete</a>
```

And it write error:

> Variable "polls" does not exist in
>   CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle:Poll:index.html.twig at line 15 500 Internal
>   Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime

in routing.yml

```
cvut_fit_bi_wt1_poll:
resource: "@CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /
```

I don't know, how write "return".

Now its work. return must be like

```
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('poll_index'));
```

> poll_index is from

```
/**
* @Route("/",name="poll_index")
* @Template()
*/
public function indexAction() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass any `polls` variable to your template here:

```
return $this->render('CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle:Poll:index.html.twig', array('pollId' => $pollId));
```

You need to assign it for using it in your template.

Comment: It is my first Symfony project, I don't know how do it. Please, could you tell me how?

Comment: You're tring to print a list of polls in your template but you dn't retrieve anything from your database. Your controller deletes a poll and returns the `$pollId` deleted... Change your template to render or get the list of polls before render it.

Comment: Is there any different way how to write return - back to the home page ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this routing pattern for deletion

```
poll_delete:
    pattern:  /DeletePoll/{pollId}        
    defaults: { _controller: "CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle:Poll:DeletePollAction" }
    requirements: { _method: get|delete }
```

And in twig template call

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ path('poll_delete', { 'pollId': pollId }) }}">
```

Delete controller with redirect

```
public function DeletePollAction($pollId) 
{
    $entity = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle:Poll')->find($pollId);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($entity);

    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('poll_index'));
}
```

Comment: I have 

return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle:Poll:index.html.twig', array('pollId' => $pollId)));

and it write error:
The controller for URI "/DeletePoll/54" is not callable.

But poll is removed. I don't know how write return.

Comment: Yes, you must to redirect your page back. Example in my answer, where poll_index is route to your polls list